# Sorting Java List by items in sublist

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist

I have a list:

```
List<List<Item>> = [["a", "one", 3], ["b", "one", 2], ["c", "one", 4], ["d", "two", 2],["e", "one", 1], ["f", "two", 1]]
```

And I would like to sort it by second value in subarray, if there is two a like then it should sort by third value and if it finds two a like from there then it should sort them by first element. 
So final result should look like that:

```
[["e", "one", 1], ["b", "one", 2], ["a", "one", 3], ["c", "one", 4], ["f", "two", 1], ["d", "two", 2]]
```

Can someone show me some good way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: The comparator answers are correct, but I caution against assuming any list you have will have any elements at all, much less two or more.  Unless this is a contrived homework assignment, you're better off creating a class with fields that you can then write a custom comparator against.  Also, be careful with the data type of the field you're sorting on... the default comparison for strings will be a string comparison, which is very different than converting "one" to the number 1 and comparing it.

Answer (score 3):

`["a", "one", 3]` should be instance of your class like

```
class Item{
    private String val1;
    private String val2;
    private int val3;
    //getters and setters
}
```

This way your list would be `List<Item>`. Now you can simply use `Collections.sort(list, yourComparator)` or if you are using Java 8 `list.sort(yourComparator)`.

As `yourComparator` you can pass instance of class implementing `Comparator` interface, for instance in a way

```
Comparator<Item> yourComparator = new Comparator<Item>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        //comapre val2
        int result = o1.getVal2().compareTo(o2.getVal2());
        if (result != 0) return result;

        //if we are here val2 in both objects ware equal (result was 0)
        result = Integer.compare(o1.getVal3(), o2.getVal3());
        if (result != 0) return result;

        return o1.getVal1().compareTo(o2.getVal1());
    }
};
```

But probably more readable and possibly easier approach would be creating separate comparators for each field and combining them. If you are using Java 8 your code can look like:

```
Comparator<Item> val1Comparator = Comparator.comparing(Item::getVal1);
Comparator<Item> val2Comparator = Comparator.comparing(Item::getVal2);
Comparator<Item> val3Comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(Item::getVal3);


list.sort(val2Comparator
        .thenComparing(val3Comparator)
        .thenComparing(val1Comparator));
```

Comment: `["a", "one", 3]` is definitely a `List`, since OP declares entire collection as `List<List<Item>>`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I know, but since it contains different types of data it would be better if it was separate class rather than `List<Objects>` or list without generic type.

Comment: for sure ))) We're here just for dummy speed coding

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do this?  Not the way you're thinking.  A List of Lists is too primitive; a List of custom objects would be better.

Write custom Comparators for the cases you want to run.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing than `"one"` is less than `"two"` (since `"o" < "t"`), and I do not see any other "string numerics"* here, a simple comparator can be written:

```
Comparator<List<Item>> c = new Comparator<List<Item>>() {

    int[] order = new int[]{1, 2, 0};  // order to compare: 2nd, then 3rd, finally 1st

    @Override
    public int compare(List<Item> l1, List<Item> l2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < order.length - 1; i++) {  
           int result = l1.get(i).compareTo(l2.get(i));
           if (result != 0)   // means that i-th elements are not the same
               return result;
        }
        return l1.get(order.length - 1).compareTo(l2.get(order.length - 1));
    }
}
```

Then sort using this comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list, c);
```

---

*For other "string numerics" such as "three", "four" and so on, if you need them to be compared by meaning, not lexographically, you would need to define special mapping, which would convert its "meaning" to `Integer` number. But this is out of scope of this question; post a new one to let not-so-busy programmers practice in dummy speed coding.

Answer (score 0):

As duffymo suggests, use a list of Objects.  A simple struct will do:

```
class Triple implements Comparable<Triple> {
    Item first;
    Item second;
    Item third;

    int compareTo(Triple other) {
        int second = compare(this.second, other.second);
        if (second == 0) {
            int third = compare(this.third, other.third);
            if (third == 0) {
                return compare(this.first, other.first);
            }
            return third;
        }
        return second;
    }

    static int compare(Item lhs, Item rhs) {
        /* Do your compare here! */
    }
}
List<Triple> list;
```

Since the struct implements Comparable, you can just sort: No need for a Comparator.

```
Collections.sort(list);
```